# My input devices have started doing their own thing

Tags: windows, mouse, input

I'm having a very annoying problem that is interfering with my work, and I can't figure out what's going on. So a little background info:

I built the PC myself last October. It has been working fine since then with no additional components added, using the same mouse and keyboard. The problem only appeared about 3 weeks ago. For fullness of information, the mouse and keyboard are both Logitech Unifying products. I forget the keyboard model, but the mouse is a Performance MX - however I don't think it's a hardware problem.

It started out with the mouse left button seemingly not holding a click. I couldn't drag and drop, essentially. After about a week, the problem mutated. Now, everything works for a few hours and then suddenly everything goes all wrong. It seems like buttons are randomly clicked. It will send my "back" in the browser, close tabs, right click "context" menus pop-up. Notably, the task bar seems unclickable. If I bring up the task manager, I can browse through processes, but I can't click the start menu, or items on the desktop. I can, however, press the Windows button on my keyboard to bring up the start menu, and I can navigate through it with the keyboard.

So my first thought was that it was a mouse problem, I switched out for a wired mouse and the problem persists. I thought it might be the "unifying" dongle, so I unplugged it and the problem persists. I don't know what is going on, and I can't pinpoint anything as a trigger.

I still think it might have something to do with the "unify" system (maybe), but I can't try using my computer without it at the moment (from boot) because I don't have another keyboard to use.

Any ideas? Thanks. (Windows 7 by the way)

Comment: Do other keyboard shortcuts work? Wild guess, but does it help to try toggling the modifier keys (ctrl, alt, shift) on and off when it happens?

Comment: I'm not sure, I didn't try that. I've tried uninstalling SetPoint to see if that helps, but I've got to use my computer for awhile to see if the problem is going to surface again. If it does, I'll check!

Answer (score 0):

Is Logitech's SetPoint software installed? Sometimes removing it helps with [assorted problems](https://www.google.com/search?q=logitech+setpoint+problems). It's just [customization software](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/mice-pointers/articles/6077) and you may not need it at all.

Comment: I've uninstalled SetPoint and I'm going about my business as usual. It generally takes a few hours for the problem to kick in, so I'll have to wait and see if it makes any difference.